# MongoDB search a key between collections

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo db with a lot of collection with only 1 document each, I want to search in each of this collection a specific key and and print its value, is possible with a query or need a Python script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to do in python

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient()['yourdatabase']

key_to_find = 'yourkey'

for collection in db.list_collection_names():
    records = db[collection].find({key_to_find: { "$exists": True}})
    for record in records:
        print (record)
```